# Domain - Computers accounts

Tags: windows, server, active-directory, windows-server-2016, group-policy

How can I not allow computers join to my domain in company if they have not existing account in AD?

I think about Group Policy but I did'nt find how to do this.
There is any a better way to do it?

I am using Windows Server 2016

Answer (score 0):

When a computer is joined to the domain, Windows will prompt you to provide user credentials for the domain to create the computer object.

The only way to stop it is if the user does not have permissions to create computer objects on the domain. By default, any user can.

So I think the better way to go about it is to restrict who can create computer objects on a domain. This article describes how to do that: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dubaisec/2016/02/01/who-can-add-workstation-to-the-domain/

Comment: thank you about your answer. I want not allow specific group of users join computer to domain that have not existing account in AD. this users needed to first of all create a computer account in AD and then they could to join computer

Comment: You can only restrict _who_ can join computers. You cannot restrict _how_ they are joined.